# Empty a slickgrid in Javascript on a button click

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

Hello I have a slickgrid with five row , how can I empty my grid on a button click?
Thanks.

My grid code:

```
var grid;
var columns = [
  {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title"},
  {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"},
  {id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete"},
  {id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start"},
  {id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish"},
  {id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven"}
];

var options = {
  enableCellNavigation: true,
  enableColumnReorder: false
};

$(function () {
  var data = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    data[i] = {
      title: "Task " + i,
      duration: "5 days",
      percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
      start: "01/01/2009",
      finish: "01/05/2009",
      effortDriven: (i % 5 == 0)
    };
  }

  grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
```

Comment: What do you mean by empty? Do you completely wipe out the data and reload, or simply empty data and nothing is displayed?

Comment: I want to completely wipe out the data , my grid has only one row so if you can show me how to empty the first grid row that will be ok too.

Answer (score 0):

So to do what you intend to do, the following piece of code should work... Please note that I did not try it, I usually do a refresh of data instead, so try it and let me know:

```
// initialize the model after all the events have been hooked up
var data = null; // empty out your dataset
dataView.beginUpdate();
dataView.setItems(data);
dataView.endUpdate();

// re-render the grid
grid.updateRowCount();
grid.render();
```

**EDIT**
I just realized that you are not using a dataview object, I always use a dataview, it's easier to play with the data. So without the dataview, you could instead try doing this:

```
// reset the dataset
grid.setData(null, true);

// re-render the grid
grid.updateRowCount();
grid.render();
```

For the method documentation, see the wiki: [SlickGrid grid.setData()](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#wiki-setData)

Comment: This is working however it empty the grid but remove even the whole unique row I have  so it looks like a grid with no rows , what I want is to set an empty values for the unique row cells I have so that the row still be in the grid but empty, so to make it easy , how can I empty one specified cell in a row? I will do the rest myself. Thanks

Comment: Oh I misunderstood then... so do you want to empty the value of 1 column (field) or the complete row? Do you want the user to do it (like editing) or do you want to do it from within your code dynamically?

Comment: I want to delete the values of the complete row, I want to do it programaticaly please.

Comment: I can't seem to find a function in SlickGrid for that purpose because this is not the usual way to deal with data. We usually populate the grid and then maybe have a user to edit some cells, but not a row change in particular. The only option I see is to update your data object which is an array, maybe something like `data[0].title=""` and then re-render the grid like I shown in my example...but again this is not the usual way to go.. we usually refresh the data with new data.